# Sending table,tr,td values into mysql including datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html-table

I came into a place, where I guess, I'm stuck.

The logic is to set:

1. frequency
2. date of first scan

It's done using below code:

```
<script>
  $(function() 
    {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var days = $("#scan_freq").val() * 7;
                var newDate = addDaysDate(dateText, days)
                $("#next_scan_date").val(newDate);
        }
    });
    }); 
</script>

<script>
function addDaysDate(dateText, days) {
    var curDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateText));
    var nextDate = new Date();
    nextDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + days);
    var curDay = nextDate.getDate();
    var curMonth = nextDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var curYear = nextDate.getFullYear();
    return curYear + "-" + curMonth + "-" + curDay;
}
</script>
```

Problems I've got:

1. When I set frequency and first scan date for the second element from the list (like HP-UX), it changes me next scan date for AIX. Same with the rest of the elements fetched from the table. Like I would change for the Linux, it will set me a next scan date for AIX.
2. I need to add functionality for the save button, that when I hit Save button, it will iterate for operating systems and store it in mysql. Same with Middlewares and theirs Save button.

Anyone able to help? Much appriciated!

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.mysqli) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: You're mixing your business logic (processing of data) with your data access layer (speaking to the database) and your presentation layer (HTML).  You really, really want to separate out all three of these things into their own distinct areas of code.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda stucked.. basically with filling out these td's and getting theirs values, as they're in a while/loop, so hell knows how much of them will be. Iterating thru them is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first crack at answering, so take that into account ;)

**Edited to make examples clearer**

If I am reading this right it looks like the loop that outputs the table gives all of the fields the same id

```
<?php
$hc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM platforms WHERE id_acc_ref='1' AND platform_type='os' ORDER BY platform_name ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hc))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  /* snipped */
  echo "<td><input id='first_scan_date' type='text' class='datepicker' value='".$row['first_scan_date']."' placeholder='0000-00-00' /></td>";
  /* snipped */
  echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

Will produce the HTML like this

```
  <tr>
  <td><input id='first_scan_date' type='text' class='datepicker' value='THE 1st DB VALUE HERE' placeholder='0000-00-00' /></td>";
  </tr>   
  <tr>
  <td><input id='first_scan_date' type='text' class='datepicker' value='THE 2nd DB VALUE HERE' placeholder='0000-00-00' /></td>";
  </tr>   
  <tr>
  <td><input id='first_scan_date' type='text' class='datepicker' value='THE 3rd DB VALUE HERE' placeholder='0000-00-00' /></td>";
  </tr>
```

note how each of the input fields have the same id, ids should be unique on a page

Based on the information given I would say the datepicker plugin is using the id of the fields internally, so it is setting the value of the field with the first occurrence of the id name; have you ruled this out? I would give each field a unique id that might solve the datepicker issue, **edit** I would know more if you post the code, or link to the library that you are using for the datepicker

with the save button functionality, can you just use a form and submit it to a php handling script. I would be inclined give the fields names using the array syntax eg :

```
<input type='text' name='scan_freq[]' value='...' />
```

then it will come through your _POST as an array

does that help?

-- more details

amended loop - one way of adding unique ids

```
<?php
$hc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM platforms WHERE id_acc_ref='1' AND platform_type='os' ORDER BY platform_name ASC");

$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hc))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  /* snipped */
  echo "<td><input id='first_scan_date_".$counter ."' type='text' class='datepicker' value='".$row['first_scan_date']."' placeholder='0000-00-00' /></td>";
  /* snipped */
  echo "</tr>";
  $counter++;
  }
?>
```

IF this doesn't help then posting http://jsfiddle.net/ of the generated source (eg right click and view source in browser) will be the way to move forward

Comment: CodeMonkey, thanks for the answer. Well, covering the datepicker issue, I have three tr's - operating systems, middlewares and network devices. I have td's inside these tr's, that are related with the number of fetched elements (platforms), so my only uniq id can be set per td inside tr, but as multiplied by number of platforms, then it's still the same id inside one tr. So I guess it's still hard. Did I understand you properly? Could you give me some code for datepicker? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I have edited my response to try and make it clearer, and I thought you already had code for datepicker, you are using $('.datepicker').datepicker({

Comment: CodeMonkey, [] worked for the issue with getting the array before sending it to mysql :) Array
(
    [hc_convert_1_in] => 
    [scan_freq] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [first_scan_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0000-00-00
            [1] => 0000-00-00
            [2] => 0000-00-00
            [3] => 0000-00-00
        )

    [next_scan_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [frequency] => 0
)

Comment: Now I'm just struggling with the datepicker, it's from the simple jquery plus jquery ui library.

Comment: "I would give each field a unique id that might solve the datepicker issue" - How can I do it? I'm using jquery datepicker, from the standard, latest jquery/ui library.